# NSFetchedResultController, Multithreading and deletion in background thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Main context works in main queue, separate operation works in separate thread and context initialized with private queue. All works great as it should, but one little problem happened.

I found sometimes when I delete records from background thread I got exception about access to fault object inside FRC. Seems that when FRC processes entries that it got and background thread deletes the same objects, this situation happens.

What should I do to prevent exception happening ? One solution that I see, is to use special property on managed object to indicate that it is (object) deleted. Or maybe I should somehow tell the background task not no delete entries until FRC finishes it work.

**Edited**: My code subscribed with NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. Destination SDK: iOS 7

MainContext:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext
{
if (_mainManagedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _mainManagedObjectContext;
}

_mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
return _mainManagedObjectContext;
}
```

Background context:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)newPrivateContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    return context;
}
```

Comment: can you show how you are constructing main context and worker context - i.e parent-child or observation of NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. And are you expecting this to work on iOS5?

Answer (score 2):

> Or maybe I should somehow tell the background task not no delete entries until FRC finishes its work.

Thats [stinky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) code. The background thread doesn't need to know what the controller is up to.

A more modern pattern for this is

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)newPrivateContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.parent = self.mainManagedObjectContext;
    return context;
}
```

and then...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *workerContext = [self newPrivateContext];

[workerContext performBlock:^{

    //stuff to be done on the background thread

    NSError *error = NULL;
    if ([context save:&error]) {
        //handle error
    }

}];
```

The work will be done on a background thread and you can remove the observation of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` since establishing a parent-child relationship between the two contexts handles that automagically.

Whether that is whole of your problem is not certain but using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` can result in odd conditions if you are not doing it exactly right.